# Change color of drop-down arrow when mouse hovers the name

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, hover

When I hover over "Services" I want the arrow to turn blue as well.  However, the arrow only turns blue when the mouse hovers over the arrow.  I would appreciate any suggestions.

CSS:

```
/* arrow */
nav ul #arrow {
    content: '';
    border: solid #fff;
    border-width: 0 3px 3px 0;
    display: inline-block;
    left: 5px;
    padding: 3px;
    position: relative;
    top: -2px;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
}

/* Change arrow color when hover */
nav ul #arrow:hover {
    border-color: #8ea5c7;
}
```

Here's [a link](https://jsfiddle.net/RE006/cxo0mntt/2/)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the link will turn blue on hovering with the following css:

```
nav ul li:hover a {
    color: #8ea5c7;
    text-decoration: none; 
}
```

You want the same thing to happen with the arrow but you only apply the rule for the arrow onto the arrow itself:

```
nav ul #arrow:hover { 
    border-color: #8ea5c7;
}
```

Which will indeed, only change color when hovering the arrow.

So you want the arrow to change color when you hover on the list item, just like what is happening to the link?

```
nav ul li:hover a #arrow {
    border-color: #8ea5c7;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/cxo0mntt/3/

Comment: Thank you so much, I really appreciate your help. :)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change the rule from `nav ul #arrow:hover` to `nav ul li:hover a #arrow`.

```
nav ul li:hover a #arrow {
    border-color: #8ea5c7;
}
```

That's all.

Comment: Thank you so much, I really appreciate your help. :)